# AvAudioPlayer "stop" not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Ok here's my problem. I have an app in which there is music playing on startup, i want to implement a simple uibutton in the settings page which stops the audio from playing.

Header:

```
int musicof;
IBOutlet UIButton *music;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
```

Method:

```
- (IBAction)music:(id)sender{
if (musicof == 1){
    musicof = 2;
[music setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"moff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"moff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.theAudio stop];
}
else{
    musicof = 1;
    [music setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.theAudio play];
}
```

}

and incase you haven't guessed already the integer "musicof" is there to keep a record of the buttons state.

This however isn't working at all, me pressing the button results in nothing but the icon changing. any suggestions?

Comment: have you checked with break points is that condition is working or not?

Comment: post your code where you create  your theAudio instanse method;

Comment: The condition defiantly is

Comment: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
        self.theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        self.theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [self.theAudio play];

Comment: If it is your code then please repplace it by

    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    
    NSData *audioData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];
    
    theAudio  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil];
    
    [theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
    
    [theAudio prepareToPlay];




and try to fetch your AVPlayer object instance on your view controller and look its address value

Comment: Apply above code inside viewDidLoad and then double check that - (IBAction)music:(id)sender method is connected with button touchUpInside inside xib.

Answer (score 0):

musicof needs to be an instance variable. You need to be accessing it like so:

```
self.musicof
```

or

```
_musicof
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply it like this.

import this framework in .h file

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

in your .m file

```
@synthesize theAudio;
```

in viewDidLoad implement this code

```
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Tum Hi Ho" ofType:@"mp3"]];

 NSData *audioData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];

 theAudio  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil];

 [theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];

 [theAudio prepareToPlay];
```

after that implement your code

```
- (IBAction)music:(id)sender{

  if (musicof == 1){
      musicof = 2;
      [music setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"moff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"moff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  if (self.theAudio.playing) {
     [self.theAudio pause];
   }

   [self.theAudio stop];

   self.theAudio.currentTime = 0;
  }
  else{
    musicof = 1;
    [music setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.theAudio play];
  }
}
```

I hope it helps  you.

Comment: I have implement it in my demo. Its working fine . Please look at my edited code.

Comment: hmm strange, does it have something to do with the fact that my settings page is in a separate view (same class)?

Comment: AVAudioPlayer not depends on view. Just check that your condition that it is coming in if case or not . If it is coming then check your AVAudioPlayer object to stop. Can you share your code here for settings page view. Delete your app and reinstall app in your device, then try it again.

Comment: I used storyboards in this app so there isn't any actual code written for the settings page, instead i just created the settings view and set its class to the original, linking the buttons to their respective functions.

Comment: I have implement it in story board based application too and its working fine here. Please replace your code with my code and check your sound.mp3 file is copied properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

you are not  `[player prepareToPlay]` to your `AVAudioPlayer` object so its take time to play audio file so first `[player prepareToPlay]` your `AVAudioPlayer` object

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create superclass:
in your appdelegate.h add:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface RADAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    AVPlayer *myAudioPlayer;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *myAudioPlayer;

@end
```

and your appdelegate.m under **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** add:

```
[myAudioPlayer superclass];
```

Try this simple and reuse for your code:

```
- (IBAction)playStop:(id)sender {
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if (appDelegate.myAudioPlayer.rate == 1.0){
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Play_BT.png"];
        [sender setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[appDelegate.myAudioPlayer pause]; //here is possible use stop or pause is depend if you use AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer
} else if (appDelegate.myAudioPlayer.rate == 0.0){

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause_BT.png"];
        [sender setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[appDelegate.myAudioPlayer play];

}

}
```

then in your file .h add `UIIMage`for your button:

```
UIButton *control;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *control;
```

come back in your `file.m`

and add this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     if (appDelegate.myAudioPlayer.rate == 1.0){

     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause_BT.png"];
     [control setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     } else if (appDelegate.myAudioPlayer.rate == 0.0) {

     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Play_BT.png"];
     [control setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
```

Hope this help you ;) if yes please rate ;)